# Display timezone name in locale Java

Tags: java, timezone

I have this piece of code in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName(new Locale("ja-JP")));
}
```

It displays the output "Pacific Standard Time". I would think, it should display this timezone in Japanese? Is this not how this library is supposed to behave?

Comment: Should `jodatime` be tagged here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java's japanese `Locale`, not your own

```
System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName(Locale.forLanguageTag("ja-JP")));
```

or better yet

```
System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName(Locale.JAPAN));
```

See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html) for supported locales in Java 8.

Comment: The full name for the Japan locale appears to be `ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese`.  Note the under-bars, it doesn't use dashes.  I dunno how much difference this will make though.  (It didn't when I tried it.)